# changing button text according to filter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

New react(hooks) developer here, question is related to updating the state when used filter,
here i have 5 buttons, two 'All' buttons, my point is when user clicks for example ' In Delivery' button then 'All' button which is under table should change its name from 'All' to ' In Delivery'at the moment it changes it to 'InDelivery'(which is not buttons name) and same thing with others also 'Delivered', 'Order' and 'All' my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-surf-t9eh3?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: if its not possible, another way doing this ?

Comment: what is your required O/P, when checking fiddle, it changes label

Comment: buttons name is ' In Delivery ' and not 'InDelivery'

Comment: You are assigning your filter value as filter label, its working as of like that now

Comment: Its because you are setting the filter value to button

Comment: how to have that functionality, getting selected buttons name to that other button

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fog-lr6os?file=/src/Test.js`  Check the updated fiddle and let me know if it helped.

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fog-lr6os?file=/src/Test.js` check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works,
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-moore-zn67w?file=/src/Test.js

I added another object called `OrderLabel`,

```
const OrderLabel = {
  Order: "Order",
  InDelivery: "In Delivery",
  Delivered: "Delivered"
};
```

And I am using `OrderLabel` to set the value of the `ButtonText` state,

```
 setButonText(OrderLabel[filter]);
```

Comment: @AkhilAravind Could you elaborate on why it won't work?

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fog-lr6os?file=/src/Test.js` check my solution, much simplified one. The less you write, the more power

Comment: @AkhilAravind That doesn't explain why you think the one I provided won't work as expected?

Comment: because you are creating the exact object again, if so it can be solved with a simple if condition. we use react to remove code repetition ( I think so ) . what is the point in creating the same object again and again...

Comment: @AkhilAravind I like your solution and I think it's better. You should add your solution as an answer. However, you stated the one I provided "won't work as expected". You still haven't stated why you think that?

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-sun-ujd5x?file=/src/Test.js`  see the same fiddle with a simple if condition.  I said it wont work, because I didnt see the new object 'OrderLabel' first

Comment: getting 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ Order: string; InDelivery: string; Delivered: string; PreOrder: string; }'.ts(7053)
' on here  setButonText(OrderLabel[filter]);

Comment: @AkhilAravind with that simple if condition you have just put 'In Delivery' what if those other buttons name are also different, should i put them also inside this if ? for example 'Delivered' is 'To home'...

Comment: @walee The codesandbox you shared shows a JS code and you are asking about a TS error? Could you please provide the code in TS to avoid confusion?

Comment: @walee , no leave the 'if' condition solution, see my solution on the comment, just update the object key:value, no other change is needed.

Comment: i'm asking that if solution because in my real code i use bootstrap and thoose 4 button are inside bootstrap modal and each has <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    onClick={() => filterData(OrderState.InDelivery)}
                  >
In delivery                  </button>, and that button which changes its name is actually the button which user clicks(the modal which contains those other buttons)

Comment: @walee `https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-fog-lr6os?file=/src/Test.js`  Check this fiddle and let me know if you need more explanation.